# running a dos application from win 7 - 64bit

Tags: windows, dos

I have an astro applicatin which is a very old one and works fine on windows 7 32 bit. I have got a new machine which runs on windows 7 64 bit and these applications are not working and throwing the error that it cannot run on a 64 bit machine.

I tried dosbox and also had it running but the issue is that the application has to print and the same was not happening inside the dosbox - need a solution on how it can be made to work.

regards
venkat

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. Is it the printing from a dos app with Win 7 64 or running it.

Comment: yes the application is a dos based and the os is windows 64 bit and i have issues running it and printing via it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using dosbox download at  http://www.dosbox.com/ , it emulates a x86 machine running dos.

Although the website is rather ugly, the product is great!

For printing in dosbox, you have to map a printer to the LPT port, see:

https://superuser.com/questions/270457/how-can-i-print-with-dosbox

or

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/268815-45-print-dosbox-local-printer

Comment: i did try as mentioned above but it runs but couldnt print from there ... let me try with the given links and revert back. ...